# Symfony 3 - Multiple Delete Form Only Deletes One Record

Tags: php, jquery, forms, symfony

I have been working on a file intranet. The latest feature I am trying to implement is a multiple delete system. Currently I render a non mapped form in my controller:

```
public function mediaDatabaseAction(Request $request)
{
$media = $this->get('media_repository')->findAll();

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('files', HiddenType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'file-list')))
    ->add('Delete', SubmitType::class)
    ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
{
    $data = $form->getData();

    foreach ($data as $record)
    {
        $file = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:MainMedia')->find($record);
        $em->remove($file);
    }

    $em->flush();

    $this->addFlash(
        'multiple-deleted',
        'Successfully deleted'
    );

    return $this->redirectToRoute('media_database_route');

}

return ['medias' => $media, 'deleteForm' => $form->createView()];
}
```

I render this form, and using Jquery add each file ID to the input as a comma serrated list. (This works by using checkbox's).

```
  $("#span-delete").click(function(){

        var checkedValues = $('.media-checkbox:checked').map(function() {
            return this.value;
        }).get();

        $('.file-list').val(checkedValues);
        console.log($('.file-list').val());

    });
```

When I look in the console, I correctly see the list. For example 234,235,236 (these are file id's).

In the controller I render the form and attempt to go trough the list and remove each one. But it only removes the first one.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The file ids are unique, I guess? Why don't you submit the ids as list and iterate over that list and delete things via _'$em->getRepository('MyBundle:MainMedia')->findById($record->id);'_? Currently the list is being used in every single data record you point to, it's not being separated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I messed around a bit and came to the following conclusion.

```
    foreach($data as $record) //loop over values
    {
        $myArray = explode(',', $record);
        print_r($myArray);

        foreach($myArray as $value) //loop over values
        {
            $file = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:MainMedia')->find($value);
            $em->remove($file);
        }
    }
```

I realised I was not looping through a list but a string. Using explode, I turned this string into an array to which I could then loop through.

Hope this helps.